# Apache reverse proxy to NodeJS app on LAN

Tags: apache, apache2

I have a LAN network with a server and client at addresses MYSERVER.IP and MYCLIENT.IP.

The server has a nodeJS app running on port 3000. Navigating in the browser from the client machine to MYSERVER.IP:3000/ connects to the app.

I would like to use a custom domain like [www.MYTEST.APP/](http://www.MYTEST.APP/), without a DNS server, and have edited the hosts file on both the client and the server.

Ping to [www.MYTEST.APP](http://www.MYTEST.APP) returns a response from MYSERVER.IP, when tested on both machines. However, http://www.MYTEST.APP/ in the browser is unreachable.

My Apache Virtual Host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>     
     ServerName MYTEST.APP    
     ServerAlias www.MYTEST.APP  
     ProxyPreserveHost On 
     ProxyPass / http://MYSERVER.IP:3000/ 
     ProxyPassReverse / http://MYSERVER.IP:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you turned off DNS over HTTPS in your browser?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I haven't made any changes in the browser. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @Shawn I doubt you can connect to a local server without an SSL certificate and server configuration for `https` when using a `.app` domain with a modern browser like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc... due to their enforcement of [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (HTTP Strict Transport Security) for that domain extension. Command line utilities will still work however. See this for more info: [How does Google force HTTPS on their .app TLD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258202/how-does-google-force-https-on-their-app-tld).

Comment: @Shawn Although this question is not in regards to a server on a LAN, the same would likely apply:  [Unable to connect my DNS with .app extension to my apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031374/unable-to-connect-my-dns-with-app-extension-to-my-apache-server)

Comment: @dan I wasnt aware that extension required anything special. I'm not opposed to selecting another, anything will do, so long as it's easier for my network users to remember than something like "My server.IP/PORT". Which extensions wouldn't require https configuration?

Comment: @Shawn Google lists `.app`, `.dev`, and `.page` [here](https://domains.google/tld/security/) as HSTS-preloaded, so avoid using those (obviously using a `.com` is a safe choice). Note that each client will have to have their hosts file edited to point this host to your local server's IP, unless you have your own DNS server setup and they using that (although DNS over HTTPS in browsers would bypass that).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller After changing the extension, I can reach MY TEST.com:3000/, I just need to remove the port number. It's part of the proxy redirect, I'm not sure why it's required still.